# How can one refer to the hostname of a docker network ip?

Tags: docker, networking, fedora

For example on `localhost` we just refer to `localhost:port` to connect to a process running on the port `port` on the local machine. Is there a way to refer to the network the container is running on so we don't have to worry and hard-code what is the ip of a specific container/service. For instance if we want to connect to the postgresql database we would just write `bridge1:5432`.

**EDIT** : @fly2matrix suggested to use the named container solution but it didn't work, `docker network inspect bridge` returns

```
    ...
    "Containers": {
        "2375b29321dc4a5947f8b63b46fe1c955f43fb1fbca64bb2adce3503380dda37": {
            "Name": "somepostgres",
            "EndpointID": "398ec0e792b836ceb5dd5d2e448e813047f9157ad90283b448e40eaf3f4f5b66",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "a72fbb333e2d8cd3b7b78205795456fadc44678348ccedc58a78510cd273505b": {
            "Name": "pizz",
            "EndpointID": "2e7aa30844a632f4d42e3d0cfa16003dfd1d86aef85e63d16c83b3a71601e134",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
```

My containers are on the same boat but if I try to connect to `somepostgres:5432` from `pizz` container it just says 'unknown host'.

Answer (score 0):

Try using named containers ,

```
#>docker run -d -it --name "container-name" {image-name}:{tag}
```

and other container can reach this container using name `container-name` of required containers.

Additionally you can also use --link option to link containers (internally it will create an entry in /etc/hosts to create alias dns name)

Comment: [Links](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) are deprecated.  [Networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/) should be used.

Comment: Thanks trying to help me, please see my EDIT